# How to stop a running command in oracle 11g DBMS

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, rdbms

I used to write PL/SQL procedures in oracle dbms. Few times I would end up in situations like Infinite loop and the query continuously running I want to stop it. If I press ctrl + C whole command line gets closed.

Comment: *"If I press ctrl + C whole command line gets closed"* means the Windows terminal window closes and disappears? How are you starting SQL\*Plus?

Comment: After I installed oracle 11g, in the start menu I would click on "Run SQL Command line" and the terminal would open.

Comment: Can you edit the shortcut in the menu, or switch to your own, and make it run `cmd /k sqlplus.exe` or `powershell.exe -NoExit sqlplus.exe` instead of calling `sqlplus.exe` directly? I'll see if I can put together an answer based on https://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/plsqldeveloper-setup-1.html#tools which is for launching SQL\*Plus from PL/SQL Developer.

Comment: I created a shortcut to sqlplus.exe and changed the target to                        
**powershell.exe -NoExit sqlplus.exe**. When I click on it, it will open a powershell terminal with sqlplus running it automatically. So when I press ctrl+C it would exit out of **sqlplus** leaving powershell terminal on my screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 11g, you need to kill the session on which that procedure is running.

You can select the sessions with below query then find out the one you want to kill/stop.

```
select sid, serial#, status from v$session where USERNAME='NAME';
```

Then kill it with below command

```
ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION 'SID,SERIAL#';
```

In 18c+, you can cancel the currently running statement associated with a session:

```
ALTER SYSTEM CANCEL SQL 'SID, SERIAL#';
```

Comment: but I am not able to type anything A underscore type of curser would keep on blinking

Comment: You won't able to do it from that same console. Open another console. Login again and try it from another session.

Comment: BTW using ctrl+C kills your command line but **does not** necessarily kill your session  nor release resources/locks. Oracle will eventually notice the disconnection but until then you query will continue to run.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Windows shortcut with the target as

```
powershell.exe -NoExit sqlplus
```

or if you don't have Powershell,

```
cmd /k sqlplus.exe
```

(I'd also recommend setting "Start in" to a new folder that you just use for SQL scripts.)

Then when the sqlplus executable is interrupted and exits, you are back on the command line where you can see the error details instead of the window vanishing.

I don't know of a way to stop a Control-C terminating sqlplus.exe, but I find this does the job in most situations.

Depending on what development tool you use ([PL/SQL Developer](https://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/plsqldeveloper-setup-1.html), SQL Developer, Toad) you can probably set up a menu item to launch SQL*Plus using the current database connection instead of relying on desktop/taskbar shortcuts.

[More notes on setting up SQL*Plus](https://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/sqlplus-setup.html).